# Mesa needs xrandr dependency

Tags: debian, source

When I run ./config it says that the program needs xrandr. But I already have it installed. Is this a environment variable issue? I'm not too sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration script is probably looking for the `xrandr` library, not the program; if so, you need to install `libxrandr-dev`.